# Symmetry in routing

Tags: pcb-fabrication, dfm

I'm moving a design to an 8"x6" panel, and got thinking as I drew the route layer(white).

[image: panel]

The cutouts on the right two boards will be routed out. The left cutout will stay with the frame. During reflow, a negligible amount of heat will be sucked up by that extra material. I already know from the previous rev that won't cause a problem. There are lots of documents published by PCB vendors saying what to do, and not to do, but I'm not finding anything authoritative on symmetry in routing. Are there circumstances where lack of perfect symmetry in routing will cause major problems? I'm particularly interested in mid-high volume production.

Comment: Matt, the white routing lines are vertical (mostly).  How are you going to separate the boards from the rails on top and bottom?  V-scoring?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about board profile routing, not trace routing.

There is no major penalty for asymmetric board profile. Most boards are at least somewhat asymmetric, and I have seen boards with no bilateral or point symmetry get great manufacturing yields. The biggest manufacturing issue with board outlines is long thin sections snapping- not an issue for your design.